# Single signon and ADFS3.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, single-sign-on, adfs3.0

I have been tasked to set up Single Signon for asp.net application (SAAS) using IIS server with a client who has ADFS3.0 for providing identity credentials. the users authenticated will be allowed to log in to the web application but i have been going through a lot of information as how to set up service provider files as the application is already running.
what settings and where do i need to configure them. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "modern" way to do this is by using OWIN.

You will have to change your application as per [Use the OWIN Security Components in ASP.NET to Implement Web Sign On with ADFS](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/29/use-the-owin-security-components-in-asp-net-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs/).

Then add your RP to ADFS and you are good to go.

For completeness. the "old" way to do this is to use WIF as in [How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application Using WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx).